# Did physicist Erwin Schrödinger propose that reality could have contradictions?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, paraconsistency, dialetheism, inconsistency

Did Schrödinger believe that contradictory or inconsistent things could exist in reality?
Was Schrödinger some kind of dialetheist?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Do you have a reference, or a reason for thinking this? He endorsed the Upanishadic view or 'non-dualism' and this can sometimes be viewed (incorrectly) as requiring a modification to ordinary logic. Also, QM is sometimes (incorrectly) seen as requiring one. So you may be right about Schrodinger, although I've never come across a statement by him on this issue. Is there one?